# zurb foundation - many duplicate css entries

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I've been using zurb foundation for quite a while now.
I'm using a bower + compass setup as described here
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

Today while working I noticed that a page was taking a while to load and while attempting to trouble shoot an issue I noticed that there are a many duplicate directives in the generated css file.

I'm sure this is probably me doing something wrong, but I don't know where to start looking and I don't even know what information to provide that might help narrow down the issue.

Foundation 5.4.5 --> actually running 5.4.7

Compass 1.0.1

Any assistance apprecieated.

[image]

*************** Update: *****************
So as it turns out I was in fact running 5.4.7
I looked in _functions.scss per @Cartucho

and it looks like the patch is there:

```
// IMPORT ONCE
// We use this to prevent styles from being loaded multiple times for compenents that rely on other components. 
$modules: () !default;
@mixin exports($name) {
  $module_index: index($modules, $name);
  @if (($module_index == null) or ($module_index == false)) {
    $modules: append($modules, $name);
    @content;
  }
}
```

@KatieK some examples from outputted css
at line 90

```
/* line 386, ../../../../foundation_master/bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

at line 2885

```
/* line 386, ../../../../foundation_master/bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

at line 3085

```
/* line 386, ../../../../foundation_master/bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: It's probably an `extend` gone wrong. Try turning on line numbers in your output CSS. But we really can't tell you more without a self-contained example.

Comment: Are you using the Compass version or libsass? There's a lot of discussions about how Foundation messed up their Bower install for libsass because it can't support the new version of SASS. The same error is probably happening with the Compass install but I don't have experience with that.

Comment: @KatieK some examples of outputted css above

Comment: @austinthedeveloper How do I know which version I'm using? I think I'm using compass because I'm using bower and compass to compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug of Foundation 5.4.5. Basically the problem started when Sass 3.4 introduced some backwards incompatibilities when handling global variables:

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html

> All variable assignments not at the top level of the document are now
>   local by default. If there’s a global variable with the same name, it
>   won’t be overwritten unless the !global flag is used. For example,
>   $var: value !global will assign to $var globally.

But this new syntax is not recognized by libsass (based on Sass 3.2 specification), so Foundation guys released 5.4.5 with a partial patch:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/8b85dc37fab3da156cdfdddfc8919667b98eb155

To resolve this, please update to 5.4.6 or higher. The bug is in the mixin `exports()` of `_functions.scss`. Try replacing it with this code (from Foundation 5.4.6):

```
// _functions.scss
// ...
// IMPORT ONCE
// We use this to prevent styles from being loaded multiple times for compenents that rely on other components. 
$modules: () !default;
@mixin exports($name) {
  $module_index: index($modules, $name);
  @if (($module_index == null) or ($module_index == false)) {
    $modules: append($modules, $name);
    @content;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

---

**EDIT**

Seems that Foundation 5.4.7 still has compatibility issues with SASS 3.4 and SASS 3.2, specially for Compass users. There are a lot of discussion like [this one](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/18856-sass-342-compilation-problem) in Foundation Forum.

According to [official doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html), Foundation works well with SASS 3.2:

> Until all Sass library's can catch up to Sass 3.4, Foundation will be
>   on Sass 3.2. This means if you have upgraded to Sass 3.4+ and Compass
>   1.0+ the commands to compile a Compass project have changed slightly.

I used to compile SASS with Compass but I give up because of those problems. So, my last advice is to uninstall Compass (usually SASS 3.4) and use libsass (based on SASS 3.2). I use the following script for installing libsass in my Ubuntu:

```
#!/bin/sh

# install_libsass.sh
#
# Script for installing libsass (https://github.com/sass/libsass),
#
# NOTES
#   http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/6803-trouble-creating-f5-project-with-grunt-and-libsass
#   http://mattferderer.com/compile-sass-with-sassc-and-libsass
#


sudo apt-get install git

cd /opt
sudo rm -R -f sassc
sudo rm -R -f libsass
sudo git clone https://github.com/hcatlin/sassc.git
sudo git clone https://github.com/hcatlin/libsass.git

cd /opt/libsass
sudo git submodule update --init --recursive

cd /opt/sassc
## Add the line "export SASS_LIBSASS_PATH=/opt/libsass"
## at the begining of sassc/Makefile
sudo sh -c "echo 'export SASS_LIBSASS_PATH=/opt/libsass' | cat - Makefile > temp && mv temp Makefile"
sudo make

echo "REBOOT!"
```

Then, reboot and check everything is OK with this command:

```
/opt/sassc/bin/sassc -h
```

Comment: Thx for this reference. no way I would have found this on my own. I updated details above. looks like I am in fact running 5.4.7 and the patch is there in the code. Is this something different you think?

Comment: @w--I've just updated my answer. Hope it helps and good luck!

Comment: ahh.. didn't see the update to the compass instructions (which suck because they don't tell you how to update an existing project). Ultimately I am running the new instructions. I'll post my exact steps in another answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @w-- Glad to help you! It's true, installing Foundation reading the docs is really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Cartucho, I was pointed in the right direction by reviewing the updated official docs.
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

Here's what I did to update my use of compass to compile foundation:

1) installed bundler

```
gem install bundler
```

2) in a temp directory started a new foundation project

```
foundation new throwaway_project
```

3) copied the stupid Gemfile to the root of my existing project. it looks like

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "sass", "~> 3.3.0"
gem "compass", "~> 1.0"
```

4) ran bundle once

```
bundle
```

5) run compass watch again using bundler (as in instructions)

```
bundle exec compass watch
```

a bunch of deprecation warnings but generated css looks good now.