# Foundation generating duplicate CSS

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass, compass

Ok, so I know there's plenty out there about this already but I can't seem to find the answer for my specific circumstances.

I'm using Foundation 5.4.7, SASS 3.4.7 and Compass 1.0.1

When I compile the SASS it is giving me a heap of duplicate entries and what should be a reasonably lean CSS file is now massive.

All the advice suggests that the problem lies around line 10 of the foundation/_functions.scss file:

```
$modules: () !default;
@mixin exports($name) {
  $module_index: index($modules, $name);
  @if (($module_index == null) or ($module_index == false)) {
    $modules: append($modules, $name);
    @content;
  }
}
```

Specifically, people are suggesting adding `!global` to the end of `$modules: append($modules, $name);`

However this isn't working for me. Suggestions welcome

Comment: Does this question help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682206/zurb-foundation-many-duplicate-css-entries

Comment: @cimmanon, unfortunately not. I'd already seen that one.

Comment: Have you updated your bower in a while? I think they finally fixed/reverted this horrible issue but I haven't started a project since I heard about it.

Comment: @austinthedeveloper I did a ```foundation new``` yesterday so it's right up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as it turns out, was simply to add `!global`

```
$modules: () !default;
@mixin exports($name) {
  $module_index: index($modules, $name);
  @if (($module_index == null) or ($module_index == false)) {
    $modules: append($modules, $name) !global;
    @content;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified mine to this:::

```
$modules: () !default;
@mixin exports($name) {
  @if (index($modules, $name) == false) {
    $modules: append($modules, $name);
    @content;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that just breaks every

Comment: There was also this forum post about a similar issue.. http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/19063-grunt---error-error-reading-values-after----libsass

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @cport1. I've tried adding and removing the !global as I said in my original post but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.